# iPhone 6 - position: fixed - not loading until stop scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, iphone

There are a lot of posts on this site that I have read but nothing is working for me and I'm not sure why.

I'm trying to make a menu that "sticks" to the top of the page as you scroll past it and vice versa (stops sticking when you scroll back up)

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var top = $('#FloatingMenu').offset().top - parseFloat($('#FloatingMenu').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/,100))
      document.addEventListener("scroll",Scroll,false);
      document.addEventListener("gesturechange",Scroll,false);
      function Scroll() {
           var y = $(this).scrollTop();
           if (y >= top) {
               $('#FloatingMenu').addClass('fixed');
           } else {
               $('#FloatingMenu').removeClass('fixed');
      }
```

CSS

```
 #FloatingMenu.fixed {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: black;
     color: red;
  }
  #FloatingMenu {
     background-color: red;
     color: black;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
  }
```

I've tried doing repainting, i've tried stopping the "inertia" scrolling (which I can't get to stop on Chrome on iOS) Either way, everything I've tried has the same results.  Works perfectly in a PC or on a Android, but on an iPhone, the menu will not repaint and be "stuck" at the top until the scrolling stops AND the finger is removed from the screen.

Is there a fix for this?  Everything I'm reading suggests that there is but notn a single solution has changed anything for me.

The strange thing is, if your scrolling back up (the menu is already stuck at the top) and you scroll past it, it auto un-sticks (even while scrolling) and works fine.

The only time its a problem is when its "repainting" the "fixed" menu.

I hope there is a solution.  Everything suggests that after iOS 8 it was fixed (and i'm testing on 10+) but It wont show the menu while scrolling until you stop and let go.  Tested on an iPhone 6 and and iPad Air 2.  safari and chrome, same results across the board.

Comment: Why not just give the header `position: fixed`, then give the `<body>` a padding top of that headers height using JavaScript jQuery. It will always look normal. If you want to add a class to it, base it off if the windows `scrollTop()` > 0.

Comment: What you are saying would work if the menu was always supposed to be at the top of the page.  In my case, its not and is only at the top after you scroll past it.

Comment: ok so on window scroll check to see if the header scroll top is less than the window scroll top, if so add class fixed and padding to body, if not remove class and padding from body.

Comment: Isn't that kind of what I'm doing?  The problem is, when I add the class "fixed" to an element while scrolling in iOS it doesn't show on the screen until you stop scrolling and lift your finger off the screen.  

The problem isn't that the code doesn't work, its just that it doesn't work until you stop scrolling and this is only a problem on iOS devices.  

In the end, I might just have to change how my layout is and make the menu at the top by default.

Comment: I've built applications in the past that utilize this functionality and worked. Maybe its your scroll function. Ill post an answer that does it by window events.

Answer (score 3):

I think I solved this question.
It's pretty funny.
Just add to style transform

```
transform: scaleX(1);
```

Or

```
transform: translateX(0);
```

And it's all

```
.fixedSidebar{
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    border:1px solid gray;
    height:100vh;
    width:17%;
    max-width:70px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `position:fixed`. This seems to have known issues with safari specifically on mobile devices. After doing some searches for hours, I believe that I may have been able to fix this issue.

The solution I used is to use `position:-webkit-sticky` for iOS safari and use `position:sticky` for desktop browsers. More documentation on this property can be found here :

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Can you please try the following code:

CSS:

```
  #FloatingMenu.fixed {
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
  }
  #FloatingMenu {
     position: -webkit-sticky;
     position: sticky;
     background-color: lightgray;
     color: black;
     width: 100%;
     height: 60px;
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 18px;
     font-weight: 800;
  }
```

JS :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var top = $('#FloatingMenu').offset().top - parseFloat($('#FloatingMenu').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/,100));
    window.addEventListener('scroll',Scroll,false);
      function Scroll() {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > top) {
            $('#FloatingMenu').addClass('fixed');
        } else if (y<=top) {
            $('#FloatingMenu').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    }
  });
```

Please note that I have removed the fixed property completely and applied the sticky property to the `#FloatingMenu` selector itself. Seems to work for me on my iOS simulator safari, and iPhone 6 Safari and on Chrome & Safari in my desktop.

**A simple working example of this fix can be found here** : [Link](http://www.inertiamusicproductions.com/testing)

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: @Maddy Can you check this URL once and see : www.inertiamusicproductions.com/testing. I have it working there with a simple implementation. Also, can you please host your page somewhere so that I can help to debug as well? Thanks.

Comment: Okay ,http://34.198.96.255/ this is the page just check the navigation bar in iphone 6

Comment: @Maddy Thanks a lot. Do you see it working on that page that I have shared?

Comment: @Maddy When I am trying that URL, I am seeing multiple console errors for top property. Is this a wordpress site? Very difficult to debug! Can you help me know where I can change the CSS classes in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139458/discussion-between-gurtej-singh-and-maddy).

Comment: @Maddy I have added a link to a working example for this fix. Please have a look and revert back if it works for you. Thanks!

Comment: I think the trick with `sticky` is that it should not require JS and should, for this use-case, work as a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add any event listener for scrolling because it can produce several errors - maybe crashing your browser. This is the first thing you need to change:

## JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var top = $('#FloatingMenu').offset().top - parseFloat($('#FloatingMenu').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/,100));
      function Scroll() {
           var y = $(this).scrollTop();
           if (y >= top) {
               $('#FloatingMenu').addClass('fixed');
           } else {
               $('#FloatingMenu').removeClass('fixed');
      }
      setInterval(function() {
           Scroll();
      }, 120);
});
```

The second thing you need to fix is your "*function **Scroll***". It's right: just a function maded to be called by a DOM element. But what if your event **isn't triggered by a DOM element**? Maybe that's your problem!
So *you can even try adding Event Listener for scrolling* just fixing that, but I don't recommend.

## JS

```
      function Scroll() {
           var y = $('body').scrollTop();
           if (y >= top) {
               $('#FloatingMenu').addClass('fixed');
           } else {
               $('#FloatingMenu').removeClass('fixed');
      }
```

## PAY ATENTION:

If the first scrollable parent of ***#FloatingMenu*** isn't the `<body>`, you should fix that `$('body')`.